# How does one put a ternary operator inside the parenthesis of a for loop

Tags: java, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I've recently learnt ternary operators and was practising them by making some old code i wrote a while back nicer. When trying to do this to a for loop in many different ways I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Ive tried:

```java
for (hotbarFirst ? (x = 0; x < mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size(); x++) :
(x = mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size(); x > 0; x--)) {
```

and

```java
for (hotbarFirst ? (x = 0) : (x = mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size());
hotbarFirst ? (x < mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size()) : (x > 0); 
hotbarFirst ? (x++) : (x--)){
                
            }
```

The first way gives me `unexpected token` errors and the second one gives me `not a statement` errors. It seems like I should be able to do this in some way or another, so am I just approaching it wrong or is there another way to do this without making two for loops.

(ignore the functions, they're for a game I made the mod in)

(Also incase you didnt notice I'm trying to iterate over a set of numbers two either back to front or front to back depedning on whether the bool is true or false)

original code:

```java
    public static int getItem(Item itemofChoice, boolean hotbarFirst) {
        if (mc.player == null) return -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size(); x++) {
            if ((x == 0 || x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7 || x == 8)) continue;
            ItemStack s = mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().get(x);
            if (s.isEmpty()) continue;
            if (s.getItem().equals(itemofChoice)) return x;
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Im trying to make it iterate the opposite way if the bool param is true

Comment: sure,
```    public static int getItem(Item itemofChoice, boolean hotbarFirst) {
        if (mc.player == null) return -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size(); x++) {
            if ((x == 0 || x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7 || x == 8)) continue;
            ItemStack s = mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().get(x);
            if (s.isEmpty()) continue;
            if (s.getItem().equals(itemofChoice)) return x;
        }
        return -1;

    }```
I want to make it so on the ``hotbar first param`` it will iterate the opposite way.

Comment: @Sweeper umm its not really formatting

Comment: I find your original code much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```java
int size = mc.player.inventoryContainer.getInventory().size();
for (int x = (hotbarFirst ? 0 : size-1); (hotbarFirst ? x < size : x >= 0) ; x += (hotbarFirst ? 1 : -1)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow this is kinda what I was trying to do in the second attempt but this makes way more sense. I like what you did with the += and the minus one. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: @ArthurTeaTree I was going to post my own answer with more explanation, but Andreas did first. I don't want to repeat the same answer again, so I'll explain briefly here. The reason why your attempts did not work is because the ternary operator expects _expressions_ as its operands, but the for loop expects _statements_ before the first `;` and after the second `;`. Therefore you should only rewrite the different _expressions_ in your two for loops into ternary operator expressions, which is what Andrea's answer did.

Comment: @Sweeper To nitpick a bit: It expects ["expression statements"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) there, not just statements. An `if` block is also a statement, but not possible there :P. Just for reference also the definition of a basic for loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1

Comment: @Sweeper yeah I understand now how it works, I learnt by looking at examples in a repo, so I didnt really have a good understanding. Thanks for your help.